# How does scikit-learn's Imputer work during cross-validation pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to debug something, and I think `Imputer` might be causing me some problems.

When using `Imputer` in a cross-validation setting, what happens if the test set has no missing values, but (in an extreme case), the validation set has some column that is completely missing. I believe `Imputer` will then remove that entire column. Then the classifier will be given an input of a lesser dimension?

I think the reverse case can also lead to problems (training data has a completely missing column, but validation data is complete).

How does `Imputer` deal with these situations?

My usage is something like this:

```
imputer = Imputer(missing_values="NaN", axis=0,  strategy="mean", verbose=5)
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[("imputer", imputer), ('my_classifier', my_classifier)])
gs = GridSearchCV(pipe, cv=5)
gs.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case

> "test set has no missing values, but (in an extreme case), the
>   validation set has some column that is completely missing"

It should not create any problem since the strategy for the imputer is `replace by mean`, meaning, each missing value get replaced by the mean of the column. If the imputer is fit on the first set (training set) than the mean of the column is known and the imputer can replace each NaN with this value. The interesting part is when the imputer is fitted on a case where a complete column is missing, in that case the mean of the column would be NaN and for sure would cause a problem, it would indeed remove your column and cause an error later in your pipeline.

Comment: The [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html) say "When axis=0, columns which only contained missing values at fit are discarded upon transform."

Comment: aaah thank you, my mistake! That is not so nice indeed.

Comment: Actually, doesn't this mean that if a test column is all NaN, then essentially that column will be removed from both the test and validation sets? I'm not sure how to interpret it...

Comment: Could be, I have to run some tests to verify this, interesting question at least :) thanks